# Post-Redirect-Get with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, http, post-redirect-get

I have a web page that implements the *post/redirect/get* pattern to avoid double posts in a simple CRUD application.

The intended request/response sequence here is:

1. browser sends data via `POST`
2. server modifies the DB, responds with status `302 Moved Temporarily` and a `Location` header
3. browser follows the redirect via `GET`
4. server responds with the updated page

This is how it is supposed to work – and it does, in Chrome for example.

Internet Explorer 9, however, sends step 3 as a `POST`, too (including the complete set of form data!). Why? What should I do to make it use `GET`?

I should add that apart from the query string the redirect goes to the same location as the form target.

I've tried:

- all available of rendering modes (IE7, IE8, IE9, Quirks, Standards, Compat)
- a full DOCTYPE
- a relative URL or an absolute one in the `Location` header
- HTTP Status 303 (just to see if that makes any difference)

Comment: Works for me with the most simple example possible, no DOCTYPE at all, etc. Are you triple sure that IE9 actually does send a second identical POST request? No proxies or anything else in the middle?

Comment: Well, looking at the network tab in the debugger tells me this. The server also receives a POST.

Comment: RFC 2616 for HTTP/1.1 states, in section 10.3.3 for [status code definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that a browser reacting to a `302` response should *not* change the method being used - so a POST should stay a POST. IE is actually doing it right. But a `303` *should* become a GET, so IE is doing *that* wrong, according to your last bullet point.

Comment: @StephenP I'll try some more tomorrow. Thanks for link to the spec.

Comment: Has there been any resolution on this? I'm seeing the same exact behavior in IE10 and IE11. Even sending a 303 response does not work.

Answer (score 4):

The correct status code if you want a GET is *303*, although 301 and 302 will also do what you want in common browsers.

If this is not working, something else probably is wrong. An HTTP trace would be helpful for finding what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but it seems like IE9 doesn't actually sent "POST" after redirect 30x - it just displays it in his internal debugger.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem as the OP, but it's very similar (Post-Redirect-Get + IE9). I have just confirmed that it's the debugger in my case.

Comment: Me as well. In IE9 mode, Network dev panel says POST->POST for 303 but server says it's receiving POST->GET. :(

Answer (score 2):

I noticed similar behavior.  Turns out IE11's internal debugger was reporting a POST but using a third party app (Fiddler) it reported the request as being a GET.  If you see a POST in response to a 303/302, double check it with an outside app.