# IE ignores 303 redirect in POST -> redirect -> GET scenario

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, http-post, post-redirect-get

I have an OAuth2 enabled site that experiencing issues related to how IE is handling the 303 response. In the flow, 3 redirects occur.

```
### Chrome/Firefox
POST idp.com/login           (res 302 -> idp.com/authenticate)
GET  idp.com/authenticate    (res 302 -> app.com/oauth2/callback)
GET  app.com/oauth2/callback (res 303 -> app.com/home)
GET  app.com/home

### IE
POST idp.com/login           (res 302 -> idp.com/authenticate)
POST idp.com/authenticate    (res 302 -> app.com/oauth2/callback)
POST app.com/oauth2/callback (res 303 -> app.com/home)
POST app.com/home
```

IE seems to be maintaining the original request method for some reason. I tried to at least break from the original POST response on my server (app.com) by returning a 303 but that did not solve the issue either. This is unexpected since RFC 2068 states that for a `303 - See Other` response, the following should be honored

> The response to the request can be found under a
>   different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that
>   resource. This method exists primarily to allow the output of a
>   POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected
>   resource.

I even tried a 307 response with no success. Does anyone have any ideas on what's happening here?

Comment: seeing a similar behavior when doing OAuth to LinkedIn - IE is POSTing the callback not GETing it.

Comment: related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912200/post-redirect-get-with-internet-explorer but still no answer

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered a similar problem with LinkedIn OAuth and my application, I solved this in a particularly inelegant manner. I allowed the POST method for my callback address and then internally in my servlet implementation treated it the same as if it were a GET call.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = ApiValues.LINKEDIN_CALLBACK, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "oauth_token", required = false) String tokenString,
        @RequestParam(value = "oauth_verifier", required = false) String verifierString) throws ServletException, IOException {

    handleCallBack(request, response, tokenString, verifierString);
}


@RequestMapping(value = ApiValues.LINKEDIN_CALLBACK, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "oauth_token", required = false) String tokenString,
        @RequestParam(value = "oauth_verifier", required = false) String verifierString) throws ServletException, IOException {

    handleCallBack(request, response, tokenString, verifierString);
}
```

Noted it only seems that IE (and older versions of IE) are providing this problem, Chrome, Firefox and Safari all seem to redirect to GET as per spec.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe the IE debugger tools if you're using it. The network panel will combine previous request (POST) with current request (GET) for 303 & 302. Thus, you will see a POST in network panel, but the truth is only GET request. Try to use Charles, or other HTTP monitor tool to check the requests.